# Is it possible to get Git clone URL from iPhone?

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I usually clone GitHub repositories by clicking on "Code" (cf. image), but this doesn't appear on the same page if I access it from my iPhone. Is there any other way to get the URL?

[image: Desktop version of GitHub]

Answer (score 0):

If you tap the extension icon (little puzzle symbol) on the left of the address bar in safari, you can activate the desktop version and decrease the fontsize of the current website. At 50% that code button will be visible.